# Find image placed in Powerpoint 16 file's slide.xml file

Tags: powerpoint, openxml

So I have upzipped a Powerpoint 16 presentation and I am looking at the XML from a slide from the ppt/slides/ directory. I am searching for a reference to the image that is place on this slide, I THINK it is one of the `<a:ext uri=` references, but if it is I have no clue how to decode that URI into something readable. I just need the name of the image placed in the file. I am currently working on these files as text files mostly from the command line or using BBEdit.

`<p:sld xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main"><p:cSld><p:spTree><p:nvGrpSpPr><p:cNvPr id="1" name=""/><p:cNvGrpSpPr/><p:nvPr/></p:nvGrpSpPr><p:grpSpPr><a:xfrm><a:off x="0" y="0"/><a:ext cx="0" cy="0"/><a:chOff x="0" y="0"/><a:chExt cx="0" cy="0"/></a:xfrm></p:grpSpPr><p:sp><p:nvSpPr><p:cNvPr id="2" name="Title 1"><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{FF2B5EF4-FFF2-40B4-BE49-F238E27FC236}"><a16:creationId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" id="{B8809CFD-BA0C-B949-842F-AF9DC6782107}"/></a:ext></a:extLst></p:cNvPr><p:cNvSpPr><a:spLocks noGrp="1"/></p:cNvSpPr><p:nvPr><p:ph type="title"/></p:nvPr></p:nvSpPr><p:spPr><a:xfrm><a:off x="1425631" y="380758"/><a:ext cx="7103533" cy="927452"/></a:xfrm></p:spPr><p:txBody><a:bodyPr><a:noAutofit/></a:bodyPr><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US" dirty="0"/><a:t>&lt;Module Title&gt;</a:t></a:r></a:p></p:txBody></p:sp><p:sp><p:nvSpPr><p:cNvPr id="8" name="Rectangle 7" title="keystrokekeystrokekeystroke"><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{FF2B5EF4-FFF2-40B4-BE49-F238E27FC236}"><a16:creationId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" id="{2D7DBD16-C48C-A14E-A06C-D1FA8D4D56EB}"/></a:ext></a:extLst></p:cNvPr><p:cNvSpPr/><p:nvPr/></p:nvSpPr><p:spPr><a:xfrm><a:off x="1153056" y="1471353"/><a:ext cx="6837888" cy="4542163"/></a:xfrm><a:prstGeom prst="rect"><a:avLst/></a:prstGeom></p:spPr><p:style><a:lnRef idx="2"><a:schemeClr val="accent1"><a:shade val="50000"/></a:schemeClr></a:lnRef><a:fillRef idx="1"><a:schemeClr val="accent1"/></a:fillRef><a:effectRef idx="0"><a:schemeClr val="accent1"/></a:effectRef><a:fontRef idx="minor"><a:schemeClr val="lt1"/></a:fontRef></p:style><p:txBody><a:bodyPr rtlCol="0" anchor="ctr"/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="ctr"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US" dirty="0"/><a:t>Module Open Image</a:t></a:r></a:p></p:txBody></p:sp><p:sp><p:nvSpPr><p:cNvPr id="3" name="Shape_27"><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{FF2B5EF4-FFF2-40B4-BE49-F238E27FC236}"><a16:creationId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" id="{29E47EB4-A9BC-C843-A78D-94CF7CDCFA5D}"/></a:ext></a:extLst></p:cNvPr><p:cNvSpPr/><p:nvPr/></p:nvSpPr><p:spPr><a:xfrm><a:off x="1153056" y="1471353"/><a:ext cx="6837888" cy="4542163"/></a:xfrm><a:prstGeom prst="rect"><a:avLst/></a:prstGeom><a:blipFill><a:blip r:embed="rId2"/><a:stretch><a:fillRect/></a:stretch></a:blipFill></p:spPr><p:style><a:lnRef idx="2"><a:schemeClr val="accent1"><a:shade val="50000"/></a:schemeClr></a:lnRef><a:fillRef idx="1"><a:schemeClr val="accent1"/></a:fillRef><a:effectRef idx="0"><a:schemeClr val="accent1"/></a:effectRef><a:fontRef idx="minor"><a:schemeClr val="lt1"/></a:fontRef></p:style><p:txBody><a:bodyPr rtlCol="0" anchor="ctr"/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="ctr"/><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/></a:p></p:txBody></p:sp></p:spTree><p:extLst><p:ext uri="{BB962C8B-B14F-4D97-AF65-F5344CB8AC3E}"><p14:creationId xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" val="331219587"/></p:ext></p:extLst></p:cSld><p:clrMapOvr><a:masterClrMapping/></p:clrMapOvr></p:sld>`

So am I close? Is it one of those URI's? If so, how do I decode it? If it is not one of those URI's then were would I find a reference to the slide on the file. I have done the obvious and searched the entire pptx zip file and have not found anything with .jpg in the text that references a file. 
I realize this is a lot to ask in a single question, and for that I am sorry. I am just sort of lost at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

For readable XML, look into a text editor like NotePad++, where you can prettify the text into indented lines.

There's no photo on this. There's a title "Module Title", a rectangle colored in Accent 1 with the text "Module Open Image", and another shape, also colored in Accent 1 but without text.

Here's what a slide with a picture looks like:

```
<p:sld xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main">
  <p:cSld>
    <p:spTree>
      <p:nvGrpSpPr>
        <p:cNvPr id="1" name=""/>
        <p:cNvGrpSpPr/>
        <p:nvPr/>
      </p:nvGrpSpPr>
      <p:grpSpPr>
        <a:xfrm>
          <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
          <a:ext cx="0" cy="0"/>
          <a:chOff x="0" y="0"/>
          <a:chExt cx="0" cy="0"/>
        </a:xfrm>
      </p:grpSpPr>
      <p:pic>
        <p:nvPicPr>
          <p:cNvPr id="5" name="Picture 4">
            <a:extLst>
              <a:ext uri="{FF2B5EF4-FFF2-40B4-BE49-F238E27FC236}">
                <a16:creationId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" id="{0966E3E9-FCFA-4DDB-B218-46F441B47F87}"/>
              </a:ext>
            </a:extLst>
          </p:cNvPr>
          <p:cNvPicPr>
            <a:picLocks noChangeAspect="1"/>
          </p:cNvPicPr>
          <p:nvPr/>
        </p:nvPicPr>
        <p:blipFill>
          <a:blip r:embed="rId2"/>
          <a:stretch>
            <a:fillRect/>
          </a:stretch>
        </p:blipFill>
        <p:spPr>
          <a:xfrm>
            <a:off x="4388972" y="1200719"/>
            <a:ext cx="3414056" cy="4456562"/>
          </a:xfrm>
          <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
            <a:avLst/>
          </a:prstGeom>
        </p:spPr>
      </p:pic>
    </p:spTree>
    <p:extLst>
      <p:ext uri="{BB962C8B-B14F-4D97-AF65-F5344CB8AC3E}">
        <p14:creationId xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" val="2510507612"/>
      </p:ext>
    </p:extLst>
  </p:cSld>
  <p:clrMapOvr>
    <a:masterClrMapping/>
  </p:clrMapOvr>
</p:sld>
```

The picture is not stored in the slide, it is only referenced. `<a:blip r:embed="rId2"/>` is the reference. Embedded photos are renamed and stored in the media folder. To find its format, you would check the *slideX.xml.rels* file (where X is the same slide number as the one you're checking) for rId2 to find that it is called **image1.png** inside the file.

Comment: So my goal here is to be able to add some "Alt Text" to the photo that is placed into the PPT slide. From what I can tell the "Alt Text" information goes into the main slide1.xml file. So if the file is embedded, how do I match what is in slide1.xml.rels with what is in slide1.xml?

Comment: I see, I thought you were after the file format of the photo. For adding alt text, check out the Productivity Tool in the Open XML SDK. Using it, you can open 2 files, one with alt text and the other without, to compare them. Then click on the View Package Code tab to see the C# code that would turn one into the other.

Comment: I am on a Mac, so using the SDK isn't practical in my case. I was hoping to be able to work with the raw XML, but that is looking impractical as well.

Comment: @ChrisNorman Alt Text is the `descr` attribute in `<p:pic>.<p:nvPicPr>.<p:cNvPr id="5" name="My Picture Name" descr="My Alt Text">`. That is what PowerPoint uses - is there any reason you can't use that attribute to add your alt text?